# java.sql.SQLException: Host 'xx.xx.xxx.xxx' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server

Tags: mariadb

I'm getting the below error when trying to connect to database server from client:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Host 'xx.xx.xxx.xxx' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server
```

User ID connecting to database has full access and is allowed to connect from remote servers (checked the mysql.user (GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database.* TO 'userid'@'%';)). 
Moreover, I receive this error intermittently. Sometimes it works without any issues.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Firewall?  NAT server?  Missing GRANT?  Proxy server?

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the network issue/glitch during that time.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the host was blocked due to too many connection errors. To fix this, execute `FLUSH HOSTS` on that server to remove that error. To prevent it, increase `max_connect_errors` to a higher value.